# Limit question $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^\left(e^x\right)=1^\infty $indeterminate

Tags: calculus, limits

In that problem

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^\left(e^x\right)$$

I use $\ln$, then it gave me $0\times\infty$ indeterminate, then I use L'Hospital Rule but I cannot reach the any answer.

Sorry for grammatical mistakes, my native language is not English.

Comment: Look at the logarithm.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown It seems the asker has already tried this way.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Let

$$ \left(1-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{(e^x)}= \left[\left(1-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{x}\right]^{\dfrac{e^x}x}$$

and use standard limits.

As an alternative we can use that

$$\left(1-\frac1x\right)^{e^x}=e^{e^x\log \left(1-\frac1x\right)}=e^{\frac{e^x}{x}\frac{\log \left(1-\frac1x\right)}{\frac1x}}$$

and use l’Hospital separately for the two parts

- $\frac{e^x}{x}$
- $\frac{\log \left(1-\frac1x\right)}{\frac1x}$

Comment: After that,I used log but I could not find anything.

Comment: @HuseyinOkanDemir We know that $\left(1-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{x}\to \frac 1e$, right?

Comment: Sorry,I could not notice,thanks.

Comment: @HuseyinOkanDemir Do not hesitate to ask for any clarification.

Comment: How can I prove that $ \left(1-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{x}\to \frac 1e $

Comment: It is a standard limit, didn’t you covered that in the class?

Comment: No,but I captured this question from last year's Midterm.

Comment: I’ve added sm alternative way in order to use l’Hospital. But it should be better if you revise standard limits.

Comment: Initially,I did these but I found infty*0 indeterminate

Comment: You should find $\infty \cdot (-1)$.

Comment: thanks,I made a mistake in taking a derivative.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Determine first the limit of the log with an *asymptotic equivalent*:
$$\mathrm e^x\ln\Bigl(1-\frac 1x\Bigr)\sim_{x\to\infty} \mathrm e^x\cdot\Bigl(-\frac1x\Bigr).$$

Answer (score 0):

Use $$0 \leq e^{e^x  \ln(1-1/x)} \leq e^{-e^x /x}$$ and take the limit, which gives 0.

Comment: I do not understand exactly, could you explain?

Comment: @HuseyinOkanDemir the first expression is same as your function since $x=e^{lnx}$ for any positive $x$

Comment: I understood that,but I did not  understand  $\leq e^{-e^x /x}$

Comment: @HuseyinOkanDemir $\ln(1+x) \leq x$ for $x>-1$ .